# Proceso correcto

Tags: android, android-studio, android-asynctask

Necesito que mi Android-App recupere mediante http-get la configuración desde el servidor una vez cada hora.

Soy nuevo en Android, llevo días "peleándome"... Finalmente lo he realizado mediante AlarmManager. Con setInexactRepeating (tipo de alarma RTC_WAKEUP) disparo AlarmReceiverTEST (BroadcastReceiver) y este llama a MyTestService (IntentService) que hace la llamada GET mediante un AsyncTask.

Antes he realizado varios intentos. En ambos la App dejaba de funcionar tras varias alarmas:

- Llamar la AsyncTask desde el BroadcastReceiver (sin usar un Service).
- La alarma despieta un Service directamente (mediante PendingIntent.getService) que llama la AsyncTask.

Este es el código definitivo. Por favor, decidme si voy bien...

**1. AndroidManifest.xml**  Defino el receiver y el service:

```
<receiver android:name="AlarmReceiverTEST" android:enabled="true" />
<service android:name=".MyTestService" android:exported="false" />
```

**2. AlarmReceiverTEST.java**  Proceso que dispara la alarma. Este inicia el servicio MyTestService:

```
public class AlarmReceiverTEST extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent service1 = new Intent(context, MyTestService.class);
        context.startService(service1);
    }
}
```

**3. MyTestService.java**  Hace la llamada GET mediante un AsyncTask:

```
public class MyTestService extends IntentService {
public MyTestService() {
    super("MyTestService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
    new CallAPI_GET().execute();
}

public final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";
public final String GET_URL = "http://www.miservidor.org/api/getConf.php";
public class CallAPI_GET extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String sMessage = "";

        try {
            String sUrl = GET_URL + "?cfgIni=0&idInstala=" + MyApp.iIdInstala;

            URL obj = new URL(sUrl);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();           // 200?
            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { // success
                // Recuperar missatge del servidor
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        con.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();
                sMessage = response.toString();
            }

        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return sMessage;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String sResult) {
        super.onPostExecute(sResult);

        // Procesar resultado ...
    }
}
```

**4. MainActivity.java**  Programa principal; programo una alarma con setInexactRepeating, que dispara AlarmReceiverTEST cada hora:

```
// Construct an intent that will execute the AlarmReceiver
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiverTEST.class);
// Create a PendingIntent to be triggered when the alarm goes off
final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),1,
        intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
// Setup periodic alarm every every half hour from this point onwards
long firstMillis = System.currentTimeMillis(); // alarm is set right away
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
// First parameter is the type: ELAPSED_REALTIME, ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, RTC_WAKEUP
// Interval can be INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, INTERVAL_HOUR, INTERVAL_DAY
alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstMillis,
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR, pIntent);
```

Gracias de antemano! :)

Comment: Olvidé comentar que debe funcionar con Android 6.0 y 7.0 (API level 23 y 24)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si sólo necesitas que se ejecute en Android 6.0 y 7.0, no en la versión 8.0, el código que propones funcionará mientras que el teléfono no se ponga en [modo descanso](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby?hl=es-419). En este modo se restringen las alarmas programadas por el AlarmManager, con lo que tu servicio no se ejecutará hasta la siguiente ventana de mantenimiento.

Diría que es mejor que cambies el comportamiento para quitar *setInexactRepeating* y utilizar ***setAndAllowWhileIdle***. Este tipo de alarmas se ejecutan cuando el modo descanso está activado, pero suelen estar también restringidas, con lo que no podrás lanzar una alarma por minuto, por ejemplo.

Hay otras maneras de realizar lo que intentas y que se están convirtiendo en un estándar, como el [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/), o el [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling), que te permite programar una tarea poniendo como requisito que haya conexión a Internet, y establecer un mínimo tiempo de espera. Con esto te aseguras que solo se haga la llamada si hay conexión a Internet, y que no se lancen alarmas que no la podrán ejecutar, pero este método está sujeto a las mismas restricciones que el AlarmManager. Puedes intentar que el usuario meta tu app en la lista blanca si es totalmente necesario, pero **no es lo recomendable**, ya que la batería se vaciará a mayor velocidad.

Comment: muchas gracias Laura!

Comment: @JordiMC, si te ha servido la respuesta, ¿podrías marcarla como respuesta aceptada? Muchas gracias :)